# Создание нового словаря, сложением значений одинаковых ключей с разным регистром

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Категорически приветствую!

Существует некий словарь

```
d = {'dom.loc': '319', '192.168.3.1': '546', 'SoMe.loc': '15', 'Dom.loc': '6'}
```

в котором попадаются одинаковые ключи, но с разницей в регистре.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне модифицировать этот словарь таким образом, чтоб все ключи привести к нижнему регистру и сложить значения одинаковых?

То есть, должно получиться нечто типа того:

```
d = {'dom.loc': '325', '192.168.3.1': '546', 'some.loc': '15'}
```

ну, или чтоб значение ключа было сразу в `int`, не имеет значения:

```
d = {'dom.loc': 325, '192.168.3.1': 546, 'some.loc': 15}
```

Comment: Покажите код, как вы заполняете словарь.

Comment: Такой словарь возвращает `redis` методом `hgetall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'dom.loc': '319', '192.168.3.1': '546', 'SoMe.loc': '15', 'Dom.loc': '6'}

d1 = defaultdict(int)

for key, value in d.items():
    d1[key.lower()] += int(value)

print(d1)
```

На выходе будет:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'dom.loc': 325, '192.168.3.1': 546, 'some.loc': 15})
```

Дальше с полученным объектом можно работать точно так же, как с обычным словарем.

Comment: Жаль, что верный ответ выбрать можно только один. Выберу этот по праву первенства :)

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {'dom.loc': '319', '192.168.3.1': '546', 'SoMe.loc': '15', 'Dom.loc': '6'}

dd = dict()
for i in d:
    key = i.lower()
    if key in dd:
        dd[key] += int(d[i])
    else:
        dd[key] = int(d[i])

print dd
# {'192.168.3.1': 546, 'some.loc': 15, 'dom.loc': 325}
```

Comment: Лучше `dd = dict()` так будет понятнее. Повторение `i.lower()` выглядит некрасиво, лучше до проверки: `key = i.lower()`

Comment: согласен, спасибо

Comment: Забыли подправить в `if i.lower() in dd:` :) Кст, заметил что у вас `print dd`, в вопросе версия питона 3, поэтому нужно будет как функцию вызывать: `print(dd)`

Comment: не успел подправить - уже комментирий)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться методом словаря `.get(k, 0)`, чтобы вторым параметром указать значение по умолчанию, если ключа не будет.

Это упростит код, убрав проверки наличия ключа:

```
d = {'dom.loc': '319', '192.168.3.1': '546', 'SoMe.loc': '15', 'Dom.loc': '6'}

dd = dict()
for k, v in d.items():
    k = k.lower()
    dd[k] = dd.get(k, 0) + int(v)

print(dd)
# {'dom.loc': 325, '192.168.3.1': 546, 'some.loc': 15}
```

Comment: интересное использование `dict.get()`